# Proving logic equivalences

Tags: logic

How to prove elementary rules like $\phi\land\phi\iff\phi$ or $\phi\land\psi\iff\psi\land\phi$ without using truth tables?

I want to show it using the rules for the connectives, for example the rules for the two connectives involved in the former equality are

> $(\implies)$: $\dfrac{\Gamma, \phi\vdash\psi}{\Gamma\vdash\phi\implies\psi}$,
>
> $(\land):$ $\dfrac{\Gamma\vdash\phi, \Gamma\vdash\psi}{\Gamma\vdash\phi\land\psi}; \dfrac{\Gamma\vdash\phi\land\psi}{\Gamma\vdash\phi};\dfrac{\Gamma\vdash\phi\land\psi}{\Gamma\vdash\psi}$.

Using this rules, can this argument show $\phi\land\phi\iff\phi$ ?

> $\dfrac{\Gamma\vdash\phi\land\phi}{\Gamma\vdash\phi}$, then $\dfrac{\Gamma,\phi\land\phi\vdash\phi}{\Gamma\vdash\phi\land\phi\implies\phi}$. And $\dfrac{\Gamma\vdash\phi, \Gamma\vdash\phi}{\Gamma\vdash\phi\land\phi}$ then $\dfrac{\Gamma,\phi\vdash\phi\land\phi}{\Gamma\vdash\phi\implies\phi\land\phi}$

And for $\phi\land\psi\iff\psi\land\phi$

> $\dfrac{\Gamma\vdash\phi\land\psi}{\Gamma\vdash\phi, \Gamma\vdash\psi}, \dfrac{\Gamma\vdash\phi,\Gamma\vdash\psi}{\Gamma\vdash\psi\land\phi}$, then $\dfrac{\Gamma,\phi\land\psi\vdash\psi\land\phi}{\Gamma\vdash\phi\land\psi\implies\phi\land\psi}$
>
> And by means of the same argument conclude $\dfrac{\Gamma,\psi\land\phi\vdash\phi\land\psi}{\Gamma\vdash\psi\land\phi\implies\psi\land\phi}$